Solaris 10: after go from IDE to SATA a "ghost disk" appear
I run Solaris 10 in Qemu vm on Linux host.
All works fine (sata, usb, etc..)
I ran on IDE because on some old version of libvirt/qemu Solaris 10 gave a lot of error (ioapic timeout and similar) if installed on SATA disk.
Now finally those error disappear. To "migrate" Solaris from IDE to SATA I have only updated libvirt configuration (remove ide disk, add sata disk using old ide disk).
Works fine but...

From where vold take the information? On /etc/ the string c2t0d0s7
is only on file /etc/lvm/md.conf.

Disks on Solaris typically show up in /dev/; eg /dev/dsk/c2t0d0.  However state is also maintained elsewhere (e.g. /etc/devices/path_to_inst).  Instances may also show up elsewhere in the file system.
Solaris really doesn't want you messing with things directly (much to the chagrin of us old-school sysadmins) and prefers you to use commands designated for the task.
Depending on the version of Solaris these may work:

cfgadm -x remove_device c2t0d0  (this may be Solaris 11 only)
devfsadm -C, which is used to clean up devices (eg dangling links in /dev).


Solution found.
Search on fs the old controller files
gfind / -name c2t0d0   |grep vol

return /vol/dev/dsk/c2t0d0/
delete it
grm -fr /vol/dev/dsk/c2t0d0/

Restarting vold or restart os, error disappear.

Hmm, in Solaris 11 cfgadm -x remove_device c2t0d0 might do the job; dunno if that works in S10.  Also look at devfsadm -C.   Solaris doesn't normally like you messing around behind its back!  In this case it might end up doing the same thing... but it's a bad habit!

cfgadm -x remove_device c2t0d0
return error on Solaris 10, devfsadm -C is ok, add as answer please, so I can vote and close
